# LocalStorage value is not getting displayed in HTML page

Tags: jquery, html, forms, local-storage

I am able to successfully store the log values but having problem in displaying the logged values in another page of same domain. I am storing the the logged values via `localStorage` in `first.html`. My code is:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html> 
 <html lang="en"> 
 <head> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
       //code of localStorage goes here     
       })
</script>
   </head>
   <body>
    <form id="logForm" method="post">
         <input type="text" name="project" value="Project Name">
         <input type="submit" value="Log Time">
      </form>
     <a href="otherpage.html">
        This is a link to otherpage.html
    </a>
 </body>
 </html>
```

I want to display the logged values in `otherpage.html`. My code in `otherpage.html` is:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <body>
       <p>This page will show the logged values</p> 
       <ul id="theLog"></ul> 
   <button type="button" id="clearLog">Clear Log</button> 
 </body>
</html>
```

Unfortunately, `otherpage.html` is showing nothing when I am trying to display the `ul`. Can anybody tell me why it is not displaying anythin or suggest some alternative method to display it in `otherpage.html`. P.S. I don't want to display it in the same page.

Comment: But you're not calling `localStorage` on otherpage.html.... What are you expecting to happen here?

Comment: How to call `localStorage` on `otherpage.html`?

Comment: `var myHtml = localStorage['key']`

Comment: You need to include the appropriate javascript in the otherpage.html, but you can access `localStorage` across pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the appropriate function on `otherpage.html`, a page can't execute a function that exists on another page. Put this on `otherpage.html`:

```
$(function(){
function getAllItems() {
    var timeLog = ""; //the variable that will hold our html
    var i = 0;
    var logLength = localStorage.length-1; //how many items are in the database starting with zero

    //now we are going to loop through each item in the database
    for (i = 0; i <= logLength; i++) {
        //lets setup some variables for the key and values
        var itemKey = localStorage.key(i);
        var values = localStorage.getItem(itemKey);
        values = values.split(";"); //create an array of the values
        var q = values[0];


        //now that we have the item, lets add it as a list item
        timeLog += '<li><strong>'+q+'</strong>: ';
    }

    //if there were no items in the database
    if (timeLog == "")
        timeLog = '<li class="empty">Log Currently Empty</li>';

    $("#theLog").html(timeLog); //update the ul with the list items
}

getAllItems();
});
```

Comment: I have put these within the `script` but still nothing happens

Comment: Please ensure you have this in the head as well:  `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`